# Indexing Spent UTXOs

Tags: utxo, database

I want to do analytics on bitcoin data and for this I would need to be able to check in what tx a spent UTXO is spent.

For this Im going to index all spent UTXOs in a database and I need help with what database solution and data structure would be optimal for this.

I know there are open source solutions like the Blockstream fork of Electrs but its a bit bulky for my slim use case and my personal laptop.

I have a quite good laptop with 64GB RAM and 4TB M.2 SSD.

Any database people here with any good input?
Straight up indexing each UTXO like this `{utxo_hash: hash, vout_index: index, spent_hash: hash}` must be really inneficient right?

I could for example identify the utxos with block_height, tx_index, vout_index which would fit on 10 bytes instead of the 34 bytes for hash and vout_index.

Comment: "what database solution and data structure" looks like better questions for https://dba.stackexchange.com/. The particular analytics you have in mind might weigh heavily for them too.